# How to break a line and assign specific string into variables in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to cat a file and make the a specific line as output:

NAME="XXX"

How can I only assign the XXX into a varilable as $name

Comment: If the file is all shell or bash, you can `source file` and then use `$NAME`.

Comment: You can also just add it to your shell init file such as `.bashrc` if your shell is `bash`.

Comment: See same question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571739/parsing-variables-from-config-file-in-bash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is shell or bash code, **the best option** would be to `source` the file to get all variables:

```
. ./file
```

or if not everything is shell code or you don't want to execute everything in it, you can still `source` it if you filter the file before:

```
. <(grep '^NAME=' file)
```

Then you can use variable `$NAME`.

---

**Alternatives:**

Using `grep -P` if available:

```
name=$(grep -Po '^NAME="\K[^"]*' file)
```

Using `grep` without `-P`:

```
name=$(grep -o '^NAME="[^"]*' file | sed 's/NAME="//')
```

Using `awk`:

```
name=$(awk -F\= '$0~/^NAME/{gsub(/"/,"",$2);print $2}' file)
```

Comment: thank you that helps! The original file is not a shell/bash, but grep works